# textview below imageview not displayed in small devices

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a simple `textview` below an `imageview` in a `viewpager` :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

//THIS IS THE PROBLEM
<com.blazetama.skripsi.util.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

This is my layout code (the important part is the `viewpager`), the problem should be here :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/edittext_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/edittext_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/edittext_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/title_n_instruct" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutViewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/indicatorMenu"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imgHeader"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/left" 
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/edittext_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/edittext_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_weight="0.6" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/right" />
</LinearLayout>

<com.viewpagerindicator.IconPageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicatorMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

I already define the `viewpager`'s height and its parent layout as `wrap_content`, however the `textview` below my `imageview` is not shown in small devices (320dp). The result is `IconPageIndicator` is below the `imageview` (no `textview`) **instead of** the `textview` below the `imageview` and the `IconPageIndicator` below the `textview`.

And this is my custom `textview` class, note that i **dont** override `onMeasure` :

public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

```
public CustomTextView(Context context) {
    super(context );
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    init();
}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    init();
}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    init();
}

private void init() {
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"segoe_script.ttf");
    setTypeface(tf);
}
```

}

Please kindly help me, Thanks for your help.

Comment: `small devices (320dp)` I think you are confusing **px** with **dp**. I guess you mean `smaller than 320 px in height` .These devices normally have a density of **120 dpi** (ldpi) and a resolution of **240 * 320 px** (in portrait mode).

Comment: what happens if you replace com.blazetama.skripsi.util.CustomTextView with a basic TextView?  Without knowing how CustomTextView is measuring it's width/height (onMeasure) it might be hard to assist.

Comment: @CSmith Sorry i forgot to post my custom textview code. Updated in question.